# can a couchdb's database files be splitted?

Tags: split, couchdb, sharding

Reading couchdb docs I understand there's just one file for each database (excluding views). My question is: what happens when this database gets very big ex > 10TB so that the file cannot fit in a single HD?
As many dedicated servers can have multiple HDD could be useful to split this file among multiple hard drives. is it possible? or sharding is the only solution for these kind of situation?
thanks in advance

Comment: CouchDB 2.0 is coming soon, and it supports clustering out of the box. If you have concerns with your database being this large, it sounds like it is definitely worth looking into.

Comment: thanks for your answer! btw do you think soon is few months? what about bigcouch?

Comment: BigCouch *is* what is being pulled into Apache CouchDB to support this, they're already in RC mode, so I anticipate weeks, but it could be months worst-case. (I'd follow their blog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CouchDB 1.x, you needed to have a database fit on one disk. However, CouchDB 2.0 (in [RC](https://blog.couchdb.org/2016/08/08/release-candidates/)) automatically distributes your data across multiple nodes (assuming you have a multi-node setup) so you don't really have to worry about the size of the database. At least about running out of disk space